# Jboss deployment BindException and ClassNotFound exception

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I'm new to ejb and am trying to make a simple hello world application work, but I cannot connect to server and cannot figure what the problem is. I'm also getting class not found exception and don't know whether it's relate to the connection error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
03:35:52,321 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
03:35:52,490 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
03:35:52,526 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting
03:35:53,040 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
03:35:53,040 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
03:35:53,047 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
03:35:53,053 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.2.GA
03:35:53,071 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
03:35:53,074 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
03:35:53,074 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
03:35:53,086 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
03:35:53,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
03:35:53,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
03:35:53,093 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.7.Final)
03:35:53,098 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.6.final
03:35:53,101 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
03:35:53,129 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
03:35:53,137 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
03:35:53,178 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
03:35:53,224 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.1.GA
03:35:53,296 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
03:35:53,477 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\Marie\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments
03:35:53,478 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
03:35:53,478 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:9999
03:35:53,481 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment HelloEJB2.jar
03:35:53,486 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found HelloEJB2.jar in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called HelloEJB2.jar.dodeploy
03:35:53,483 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-13) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use: bind localhost/127.0.0.1:9990
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.HttpManagementService.start(HttpManagementService.java:197) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:144)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:54)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:38)
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:147)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.create(ManagementHttpServer.java:143) [jboss-as-domain-http-interface-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.HttpManagementService.start(HttpManagementService.java:164) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more

03:35:53,558 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-12) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
03:35:53,766 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: Address already in use: bind localhost/127.0.0.1:9990

03:35:53,773 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started (with errors) in 1651ms - Started 132 of 205 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 70 services are passive or on-demand)
03:35:53,782 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "HelloEJB2.jar"
03:35:53,898 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class com.businnesslogic.HelloWorldBean in Module "deployment.HelloEJB2.jar:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/businnesslogic/HelloWorldBean : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:111)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]

03:35:53,914 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."HelloEJB2.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."HelloEJB2.jar".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "HelloEJB2.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011093: Could not load component class com.businnesslogic.HelloWorldBean
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:113)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.businnesslogic.HelloWorldBean from [Module "deployment.HelloEJB2.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:111)
    ... 7 more

03:35:53,926 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "HelloEJB2.jar" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"HelloEJB2.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"HelloEJB2.jar\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"HelloEJB2.jar\""}}
03:35:53,931 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment HelloEJB2.jar in 4ms
03:35:53,932 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."HelloEJB2.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."HelloEJB2.jar".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "HelloEJB2.jar"

03:35:53,935 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"HelloEJB2.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"HelloEJB2.jar\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"HelloEJB2.jar\""}}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues as per the log :

1) Port 9990 is already in use:

`Address already in use: bind localhost/127.0.0.1:9990` - stop all JBoss process and any other process that is using port 9990 restart and let us know how it went.

2) Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]

You are running your application on a JVM that does not support the JDK that was used to compile your application. Check what Java compiler version you are using (Depends on your IDE, build) in your development environment and make sure it is 1.7.0_79 or lower.

Or make JBoss run in the same jvm version as your development JDK.

Comment: The problem was, that Nvidia Network Service was running on the same port. Stopping it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have two major errors in the log

1 - Address already

```
Address already in use: bind localhost/127.0.0.1:9990
```

This error tells you that the port 9990 is being used by another process. Typically another jboss instance. You must stop one of them.

2 - Unsupported major.minor version

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/businnesslogic/HelloWorldBean : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

This tells you that you compile the source code with one version of java and then you try to run it with another version.

Because of this errors your application is not being deployed.